# The configuration 'What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, project-reactor

When I'm running my system (Java + Spring + Reactor + Kafka), the following warning is being reported:

```
The configuration 'What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted): <ul><li>earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset<li>latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset</li><li>none: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group</li><li>anything else: throw exception to the consumer.</li></ul>' was supplied but isn't a known config.
```

**What Should I do to avoid this warning?**

I already added this value in the application.yml:

```
spring:
    consumer:
      auto-offset-reset: latest
```

Apart from that, I'm also using the same programmatic config:

```
@Bean(name="myTopic")
@Lazy
public KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiverForAdyenNotifications() {
    var receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.<String, String>create(receiverProperties(getTopicNameCardEvents()))
        .subscription(Collections.singleton(getTopicNameCardEvents()));
    return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions);
}

public Map<String, Object> receiverProperties(final String name) {
    var group = name+"-group"+ (Optional.ofNullable(activeProfile).orElse("").contains("local") ? "-local" : "");
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    return props;
}
```

And I'm using these configs here:

```
@Bean
@Profile("!test")
public ApplicationRunner paymentEventsListenerRunner(@Qualifier("myTopic") final KafkaReceiver<String, String> kafkaReceiver) {
    return args -> kafkaReceiver.receive()
        .doOnNext(rr -> {
            try {
                final MyDTO myDTO = objectMapper.readValue(rr.value(), MyDTO.class);
                ...
```

Comment: It's hard to say; please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what's wrong.